# npm's less library - how to define a subdirectory for imports

Tags: node.js, npm, servicestack

I'm trying to configure the ServiceStack bundler which uses npm's less library.

I have a number of subdirectories where I store less files.

I have an issue in that changes to my less files are not triggering on compile. They do if I reference the file directly in my bundle file like this:

```
scaffolding/grid.less
```

but not when used like this:

bundle file: `main.less`

main.less: `@import "scaffolding/grid.less"`

The first option leads to more issues regarding duplicated code and is not a viable way forward at the moment.

Having previously asked a different question, it seems that the compiler might not be finding the path to the @imports. However there is a configuration section which uses npm's less library.

```
function compileLess(lessCss, lessPath, cb) {
    var lessDir = path.dirname(lessPath),
        fileName = path.basename(lessPath),
        options = {
            paths: ['.', lessDir, lessDir + '/scaffolding'], // Specify search paths for @import directives
            filename: fileName
        };

    less.render(lessCss, options, function (err, css) {
        if (err) throw err;
        cb(css);
    });
}
```

You can see how I'm trying to add my subdirectory but it doesn't have any effect - either the way I'm defining the subdirectory is incorrect, the subdirecty has the wrong/incomplete path, or it is correct and the compiler still doesn't pick it up.

I'm stuck where to go from here.

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mistake on my part, but one which wasn't easily spottable, so I'll post the reason for my problems so that others don't spend hours as I did chasing a solution to an unecessary problem.

I was using ServiceStack Bundler - I believe this issue would also have occured on on any solution using npm's less library.

My main issue was that none of my changes were triggered on compile. I use lots of @imports and numerous sub-directories for my less files so my first thoughts were the problem was due to subdirectories, and later, due to @import statements. However neither was correct.

I defined a bundle: `main.css.bundle`

Within the bundle I called my main less file that contained all the other @imported files: `main.less`

The issue was that less would normally reserve main.css, but the bundle also gives its output the same name based on the bundle name. So both were conflicting.

Change the bundle name or the main less file name and all should work.